# regular expression: match everything but single forward- and double backslashes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match a string of arbitrary length with a regular expression (in python), that does *not* contain a single forward- or double backward slashes.

"[^/]*" works just fine for the forward slash, but "[^/\\\\\\\\]" does obviously not work in a set.

How can I match everything but two consecutive backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions) to exclude the two patterns.

```
re.match(r'(?!.*/|.*\\\\)', string)
```